Selecting All Rows with SELECT * But Records Are Not Complete
Issue
I have a Go service as a cron job to check all data from the database table once every week. The logic is very simple, the Go service fetches all rows from the source table and does some logic with the data there.
However, there is some issue where I have 3.371.351 or ~3 million rows and 400 columns from the source table and I only get about 138.912 or ~100k rows (stored in Go slice), which indicates several rows didn't fetched completely by the query, even though the query process is successfully executed.
Code
Here my Go code that perform a simple SELECT statement:
func (repository Repository) GetAllData() ([]entity.ExampleStruct, error) {
    sql := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM [%s].[schema_data].[%s]", viper.GetString("SQL_SERVER_DBNAME"), viper.GetString("SQL_SERVER_TABLE"))
    
    rows, err := repository.sqlServerConnection.Query(sql)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    if rows.Err() != nil {
        return nil, rows.Err()
    }

    var exampleStructList []entity.ExampleStructList 
    for rows.Next() {
        var exampleStruct entity.ExampleStruct
        err := rows.Scan(// scan struct here)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        exampleStructList = append(exampleStructList , exampleStruct)
    }

    return exampleStructList, nil
}

Findings
Before, I have compared the query with the WITH (NOLOCK) clause to speed up the SELECT statement and without it, but it seems the results are still same.
What interesting is, I can get the correct row count using COUNT(*) query.
I also got an information from my DBA that they have several restore activity on the database and the table to refresh the data, I assume the restore activity might affect my row fetching process.
Sometimes I got an error while fetching the data like below:
 "Error": {
  "Number": 927,
  "State": 6,
  "Class": 14,
  "Message": "Database 'xx' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.",
  "ServerName": "xx",
  "ProcName": "",
  "LineNo": 1,
  "All": [
   {
    "Number": 927,
    "State": 6,
    "Class": 14,
    "Message": "Database 'xx' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.",
    "ServerName": "xx",
    "ProcName": "",
    "LineNo": 1,
    "All": null
   }
  ]
}

Expected Result
My expected result is the SELECT statement should return the complete record that has same row count as the source table.
For instance, if the source table has 3 million rows, I also should get exactly 3 million rows from my SELECT * statement.
Specification

Go version: 1.20.7
MS SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000
SQL Server Golang Driver: https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb


You should read up on and understand all the implications of using nolock because you ever use it. Its unlikely to be what you think it is.

Does the service write any data (either back to the same database or elsewhere), or is it just reading and checking? If the latter, can you just do the reading and checking in SQL (eg, in a stored procedure)? 3 million rows * 400 columns is a lot of data, how about processing it in batches? Do you actually need all 400 columns?

@allmhuran my service just reading and checking all the data, nothing special. Can you give me the idea for the batching process? is it on the Go code? or on the SQL query level using LIMIT? And yes, I need all the columns for the business need

@DaleK I have tried to not using it, but the result is still same.

I wasn't suggesting nolock was relevant to this problem... just a general FYI... don't use it

@DaleK I see, I will take a note for that. So, is it must be the restore activity that disrupt the rows?

Exactly how you should batch will depend upon your schema. The general pattern is "use a column (or multiple columns if necessary) to filter, and keep track of what you're up to". The column(s) you use should be indexed and unique. If your clustered index is on something like an identity column, that works nicely. There are various questions covering this on SO already, for example here and here.

You should move the rows.Err() check after the for rows.Next() { loop (you are probably missing the error; errors can occur as the results are being retrieved). See the database/sql docs and this example.

That's a lot of data to get into memory. I have a feeling a go service is not the way to... go for this task. Can't you do the manipulations in the database like a procedure and then let the service call it?

@allmhuran alright, thanks for the reference, it seems simply implement the pagination approach, if I am not wrong.

@Brits I will try to move the rows.Err() and see what happen, thanks

@siggemannen unfortunately, I don't have access to the database, because is handle on other team

And you can't talk to that team? What kind of logic are you doing in your service anyway? Do you need to keep track of all rows at all times? What happens if you just "spool" the rows without storing them, does it fetch everything or is it also choking?

@siggemannen Hi I want to update you, I have contact the DBA team so they can adjust the restore time, and it actually worked. I can retrieve a complete record.

@mathiasyeremia glad to hear it! working together is a good way to fix problems :)

Solved: the cause is the restore activity, therefore I need to retrieve the data when the restore time schedule is off.
